# Advanced Custom Fields Plugin: Get file URL into Parent

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

On parent page, I've got a grid of custom field values from child pages. All text fields work fine, but I'm having issues with the file URL fields: instead of the URL it returns attachment ID.

Here's the code I'm using to display all the fields:

```
    <?php
    //get children of page 4 and display with custom fields

    $args=array(
    'post_parent' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    );

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Stripped down version, without any formatting:

```
    <?php $meta_one = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'doors', true); ?>
    <?php echo $meta_one; ?>
```

ACF's developer said I should be using get_field instead, but if I replace get_post_meta with get_field it doesn't even return the ID.

I've also tried adding URL parameter like this:
`<?php echo $meta_one['url']; ?>`
No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how ACF keeps attachment data:

```
meta_id        post_id     meta_key        meta_value

971            931         doors           666
972            931         _doors          field_25
```

As you can see if you're using `get_post_meta` it will only ever be able to return you an ID. Since not using `get_field` you'll need to do the extra step of getting attachment metadata yourself:

```
$meta_one = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'doors', true);
$meta_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $meta_one );
echo $meta_url;
```

Comment: Of course I've done that, it's set to URL and returns the URL on the child page. Only having issues with getting the URL to show on the parent page.

Comment: Well, how are you getting the other fields? Should be no different. Did you examine your `$meta_one`? Not `echo`, but rather `print_r($meta_one)`.

Comment: The code I included in the original post is how I'm getting all the other fields into the parent. It works for text fields. --  print_r still prints the ID, not URL.

Comment: @Phantasmix I updated my answer, try it out.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!! That works great. I didn't even think to look in the db, duh :) Thanks